# Why is a VYM (View Your Mind) file considered an archive?

Tags: files, archive

I use the program VYM (View Your Mind) to draw and manipulate mind maps and outlines. I find it a great application but for some reason the files it creates (.vym files) are considered an archive by Ubuntu.

So two questions, why are .vym files considered an archive and how can i change the file association to allow me to click on a .vym file and have it opened by VYM?

This is on the Ubuntu 12.04 most current version.

Answer (score 2):

There are file formats that actually are just archived XML files or something similar.

We can see [**here**](http://www.mind-mapping.org/interoperability-of-mind-mapping-software/VYM.php) that this is exactly the case with VYM format.

I'm not using GNOME desktop but I guess you should right-click the file, find an "*Open With*" item and point it to the VYM application. Don't forget to save the format association.

Comment: More precisely, if an extension is not recognized, the file contents are evaluated to determine the MIME type. Using that MIME type, the correct program is looked up.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the file you want, then click in `properties`, than click the tab `open with`.
Select the software you want to use to open the file.

Comment: Because Ubuntu sees .vym as an archive, i cannot change the file association with the properties dialog. It seems to lump together all archive file types (.zip, .rar, etc.) along with .vym files. If i change the file type association for a .vym file it changes the association for all of the others as well, not something i wish to do.

Comment: This problem is fixed, i downloaded assogiate a nifty little mime type editor and entered the vym file association.